# OpenLDAP limit max sessions per user

Tags: openldap, slapd

I have a slapd LDAP server and need to limit the number of active sessions per user. Is there a configuration parameter I can change to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think OpenLDAP can be configured to do that. It would require authenticated binds to determine who is connecting to the directory server so it could keep track of connections per user. There is a similar question in which the OP found a [workaround](https://serverfault.com/questions/238140/can-i-limit-the-number-of-connections-per-client-in-openldap). Perhaps, that may work for you. However, it's not user based limitation like you want. It's IP address based and requires firewall configuration.